# Can't start Cassandra after OS patch up

Tags: cassandra, datastax, rhel

When I try to start Cassandra after patching my OS, I get this error:

```
Exception (java.lang.AbstractMethodError) encountered during startup: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:150)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:135)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:405)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:104)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:143)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:188)
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:476)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:59
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:93)
```

```
ERROR [main] 2018-01-17 13:18:03,330  CassandraDaemon.java:705 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
```

Does anyone know why, with no other changes, I'm running into this error now?

Comment: You can use Java alternatives to point to an earlier jdk 8 version that works. I just did the same after landing on the latest jdk 8 and not being able to start DSE

Comment: This question is [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362651/is-this-really-a-good-question-not-to-be-closed?cb=1)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This seems to relate to an upgrade to the JDK to 8u161 which was released 2 days ago.

A ticket has been opened on the [Cassandra Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173)

There is no published work-around that I can find.  You might have to go back to an earlier version of the JDK or wait for Cassandra 3.11.2 which fixes the issue.

Edit: Its worth pointing out that this has now been resolved in 3.11.2 which has been released, so you can simply upgrade to this version to resolve the problem.

Comment: More info here as well: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/d7eaa0eaeae575230273a3a5c88dec15569686891b6c24b388688456@%3Cuser.cassandra.apache.org%3E

Comment: there is no 3.11.2 version available to download,  I checked at https://academy.datastax.com/planet-cassandra/cassandra

Comment: @Vikash .... http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/cassandra/3.11.2/apache-cassandra-3.11.2-bin.tar.gz

Comment: @Vikash ... there's a link on the page you went to, and a notice that says "DataStax no longer provides the DataStax Community Edition or the DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra. "

Comment: Updating Java to JDK 8u172 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 4):

To get Cassandra running I had to install JDK 8u152. Using `brew cask install java8` it wasn't possible. I tried using an [old version of the `cassandra.rb` formula](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-versions/commit/ac0ed09d12951b64f4087be60fb045caaccf6723#diff-ddb5930ea70cb853215ab5f523c0c016) but that just got:

```
Error: Download failed on Cask 'java8' with message: Download failed: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u152-b16/aa0333dd3019491ca4f6ddbe78cdb6d0/jdk-8u152-macosx-x64.dmg
```

I had to go here and log in to be able to download the DMG: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html

Protip: To still be able to install java8 using homebrew I downloaded the dmg myself, and started a server in the downloads directory:

```
cd ~/Downloads
php -S 0.0.0.0:3333
```

And changed the download URL (line 6) in the formula to:

```
url "http://0.0.0.0:3333/jdk-8u152-macosx-x64.dmg",
```

Then was able to run:

```
brew cask install java8
```

Now Cassandra is running again.

Answer (score 3):

You may download the source and add the changed method, compile and add the modified class to the apache-cassandra.jar. You can do the following:

1. Download [org.tar](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15Eo9b8MOekwBff7vzGgccPrdbqFP3FLj) containing the only class to be replaced.
2. Untar the file using `tar -xvf org.tar` and you should get `org` directory
3. Copy the apache-cassandra jar file. e.g.  `cp /usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar .`
4. Make a backup of the jar before you update. `cp apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar_backup`.
5. Expecting the current directory contains the following files:

   `apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar
   apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar_backup
   org
   org.tar`
6. Execute the following command to update the jar:

   `jar uf apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar org`
7. Replace the file to installation location:

   `mv apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar /usr/share/cassandra`
8. Restart cassandra service

Answer (score 0):

Revert Cask formula to 2017 version.

`wget https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-versions/blob/a98da98a7e4d87e9b614b3aa25af9c6c21a753c6/Casks/java8.rb -O /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/Casks/java8.rb`

change line 6 URL as suggested 
url "http://127.0.0.1:3333/jdk-8u152-macosx-x64.dmg",

brew cask reinstall java8

should work.