# Cassandra does not start cause of an AbstractMethodError with JDK to 8u161?

Tags: java, cassandra, cqlsh

My Cassandra won't start on a new installed root...

/var/log/cassandra/debug.log prints:

> ERROR [main] 2018-02-03 07:13:46,463 CassandraDaemon.java:706 - Exception encountered during startup
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject

```
root@srv49023:~# java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

root@srv49023:~# systemctl status cassandra
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2018-02-03 07:13:43 EST; 1min 8s ago
  Process: 213 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 03 07:13:43 srv49023 systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't start Cassandra after OS patch up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328661/cant-start-cassandra-after-os-patch-up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to relate to an upgrade to the JDK to 8u161 which was released 2 days ago.

A ticket has been opened on the [Cassandra Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173)

There is no published work-around that I can find. You might have to go back to an earlier version of the JDK or wait for Cassandra 3.11.2 which fixes the issue.

Comment: I used oracle-java8-installer from the ppa:webupd8team/java repository... Do you have an Idea on how to downgrade to an earlier version?

Comment: You can download the tar version here of an older JDK version. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u151-relnotes-3850493.html

Comment: However and whatever I search I will ever redirect to the 161 update.. on this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: I meant to download the tat file and place on file directly

Comment: Typo it’s tar file

Comment: Now they wrote they had fixed it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173 but whenever I do apt-get update and try to reinstall it, it won't work...

Comment: If you read the comments in that JIRA they are planning to release it along with another fix, may be next week. Wait for 3.11.2

Answer (score 1):

If waiting until Cassandra `3.11.2` is not an option, you can use an old version of Java and of Cassandra. Example below.

- Download the binary tarbell (`-bin`) of an old Cassandra version ([link](http://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/)). I used `3.10.0`
- Extract downloaded tarbell: `tar -xvf apache-cassandra-3.100bin.tar.gz -C /home/ty/src`  (more [details on extracting](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html))
- Download old Java version ([link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html)). I used `Java SE Development Kit 8u151` (1.8.151)
- Remove incompatible version of Java (`Java 1.8.161`) ([instructions](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_uninstall.xml)).
- For example:

  > [root@localhost ty]# rpm -qa | grep java
  >
  > > tzdata-java-2017b-2.fc27.noarch
  > >
  > > abrt-java-connector-1.1.0-14.fc27.x86_64
  > >
  > > java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.144-7.b01.fc27.x86_64
  > >
  > > javapackages-tools-5.0.0-7.fc27.noarch
  >
  > [root@localhost ty]# sudo yum remove java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.144-7.b01.fc27.x86_64
- Install older version of Java: `rpm -ivh jdk-8u151-linux-x64.rpm`
- Cd to your Cassandra directory and try starting Cassandra: `bin/cassandra -f` (more [instructions](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html))

Comment: Awesome work! For ubuntu also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/536134/install-specific-java-version-for-12-04 to update java