# Running error while using ./cassandra -f

Tags: python, cassandra

I have installed Cassandra from DataStax and the version is 3.0.9 and my java version is 1.8.0_162. When I tried to do multi-node cluster. I used two computers one is mac and another one is ubuntu and the Mac started running and I had a problem with Linux. So when I thought of starting with single node cluster with mac, I reinstalled everything and I tried to run ./cassandra -f and it stops at some point and not running.

Error I get:

```
ERROR 08:03:44 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
```

I reviewed the same question from others but nothing helps. Please let me know where I am wrong and how can I run it properly.

Thanks

[image: View of my terminal with error]
[image: View of my terminal with error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cassandra does not start cause of an AbstractMethodError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597284/cassandra-does-not-start-cause-of-an-abstractmethoderror)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known error that happens only with Java 8 u161 and later. If you downgrade to Java 8 u15x Cassandra should run fine.

Here is the mailing thread for when the issue was discovered: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/fcc963f2d20246d97a83bff662121ed43026efb643f57d0fa28ee9fe@%3Cuser.cassandra.apache.org%3E

The next version of Cassandra will solve the issue.

Comment: Hi, Simon. I have installed java 1.8.161 so also you mean to say it wont work for any java8 version? Thanks

Comment: Could you please suggest me which version of cassandra and java is compatible without any issues?

Comment: java 1.8u152 should be fine

Comment: I end up installing Riak because jdk 1.8 152 is still not so easy to download for oracle site. But thanks guys

Comment: @sana It is recommended to run Cassandra with Oracle Java but if you're just trying things out Riak should be fine. But you can still download older versions of Oracle Java. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/downloading-java-jdk-on-linux-via-wget-is-shown-license-page-instead

Comment: Hi, @SimonFontanaOscarsson I actually see that i am using java 1.8.151 now and still i find this problem. cassandra is not starting at all at first place. So i have now successfully installed Riak in both my computers it seems to run fine at least and thanks. I worry that cassandra may raise some error in my later approaches if i don't use the same java as it requires.