# Unnable to start cassandra using bin/cassandra -f

Tags: java, cassandra, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

```
ERROR [main] 2018-03-09 08:15:25,174 CassandraDaemon.java:706 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
```

Comment: That stacktrace looks very small. Any change you have a full stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the JDK version issue. Which Cassandra version you are using and which JDK version?  For C* version less than 3.11.2, there was an upgrade in JDK to 8u162 which is incompatible.

> > A change to one of these, introduced in Oracle JDK 1.8.0_162 is incompatible, which means we cannot build using that JDK version .

Please check this below link:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173

Upgrade you C* version to 3.11.2 to fix this issue or lower JDK version to JDK 1.8.0_152.

**Related Links:**

https://serverfault.com/questions/894687/error-when-starting-cassandra-for-first-time

[Can't start Cassandra after OS patch up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328661/cant-start-cassandra-after-os-patch-up)