# Cassandra : Exception on startup

Tags: cassandra

I am getting the following erorr on starting Cassandra:

```
ERROR [main] 2018-04-09 18:19:25,014 CassandraDaemon.java:675 - 
Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:135) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:405) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:104) ~[main/:na]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:139) [main/:na]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:183) [main/:na]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:569) [main/:na]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:658) [main/:na]
```

Can someone please tell me where I could be going wrong ? I haven't made any changes since the last successful run, so I'm confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't start Cassandra after OS patch up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328661/cant-start-cassandra-after-os-patch-up)

Comment: You upgraded Java to latest, and it broke the Cassandra - see answers in linked entry

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks !