# Unable to connect to any servers

Tags: cassandra, debian, cqlsh

I have lost connection to Cassandra server and I am not able to restore it back.

When I run: `sudo service cassandra status` I can see service is running:

```
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2018-04-27 13:06:21 UTC; 4min 5s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 18479 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/cassandra stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18539 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cassandra.service

Apr 27 13:06:21 serveur-1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: distributed storage system for structured data...
Apr 27 13:06:21 serveur-1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
```

But When I run  `> cqlsh`, I got the following:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Comment: Does `nodetool status` give you any output?  If not, then Cassandra is not running.

Comment: Also, I think you're running into CASSANDRA-14173 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328661/cant-start-cassandra-after-os-patch-up

Comment: `nodetool status` gives also an error of connection failure.

Comment: I have installed cassandra 3.11 on my local machine. I got this error few minutes at the start. and then `cqlsh` works. but I couldn't figure out why it worked suddenly. `sudo service cassandra status` show the same output on both local machine and on server.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Cassandra or JDK. they are the same on server and on my local machine. the problem started when I upgraded cassandra on server. `/var/lib/cassandra/data` contains non compatible schemas. is there a way to restore my data ?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting content of directory `/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog` and restarting cassandra fixed my issue !

Comment: Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Check that Cassandra really accepts connections through loopback interface.

See what's in your `cassandra.yaml` under `listen_address` and `listen_interface` property

```
# cat /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml  | grep listen
...
listen_address: 172.17.0.2
...
```

If you see a non local address, it might happen that `cqlsh` needs to connect through another interface to your Cassandra instance. Try this command (by replacing the IP with the same IP in configuration:

```
# cqlsh 172.17.0.2
```

You can check which hosts are allowed co access your Cassandra service using the following command

```
# netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9042            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:38899         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 20f1802:afs3-fileserver 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
```

`0.0.0.0` means that my Cassandra instance allows connection from both loopback and ethernet interface.

Comment: I got only this line uncommented: `listen_address: 127.0.0.1`

Comment: executing: `sudo lsof -i :9042` give empty result. so cassandra is not listening

Comment: You should look for port 9042 in case of Cassandra. I don&#39;t see it in your sent screenshot. Can you send the whole execution result of `netstat`?

Comment: There is nothing listening on port 9042. that's the issue. I will send whole execution now.

Comment: Try to start Cassandra again. Also look for the logs if there was any error during startup. In logs look for the message: `state jump to normal`. This indicates that node is up-and-running.

Comment: Yes, there is an error in log, but I am not able to understand it. https://imgur.com/a/Q8xxSgD

Comment: Unfortunately some details are missing from screenshot. I suspect that there is a port collision somewhere. Try to stop some of the services locally and start Cassandra again.

Comment: i have chnaged the listen address and rpc address and port neither works for me

Answer (score 1):

Delete all content from commitlog and it will work.